# How should I write documentation for cases of HttpResponseException being thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, asp.net-web-api, http-status-codes

I'm wondering how to write documentation comments for [HttpResponseException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) exceptions thrown by ASP.NET Web API controllers? The thing is that, normally you throw a different kind of exception for each case and hence write a documentation comment for each exception type, e.g `/// <exception cref="ResourceNotFound">Resource not found</exception>`. However, with HttpResponseException, the `StatusCode` property of the exception is what identifies the error case.

How should I document each of the cases where `HttpResponseException` may be thrown, each identified by a status code, corresponding to how you otherwise write an `/// <exception></exception>` comment per exception type?

Comment: i think you wouldn't need to document the different StatusCodes. Just put a link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.108).aspx into the description of the StatusCode-Property and whoever reads the documentation can browse to the MSDN's StatusCode-Documentation

Comment: @Ingo No, I mean I want to document each HttpResponseException/StatusCode pair my methods may throw. See what I mean? If my method can throw HttpResponseException with HttpStatusCode.NotFound or HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError I need to document exactly that, but it doesn't correspond to standard exception documentation.

Comment: Is that really necessary? The HTTP status codes all have standard meanings. Just include a hyperlink to Wikipedia or some other resource.

Comment: @ChristianHayter I don't mean to document the status codes per se, but the different cases for which a method may throw HttpResponseException (i.e. one case is HttpStatusCode.NotFound, another is HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError). See what I mean?

Comment: Maybe to clear up some confusion: HttpStatusCode.NotFound = 404 & HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError = 500 for the actual HTTP status code value. Client-side code that handles HTTP responses should handle these standard codes per their definition in the HTTP spec. As Christian Hayter says, these code are already documented and well known.

Comment: @SixtoSaez You guys are misunderstanding me I think; I just want to document the different scenarios for which API controller methods can throw HttpResponseException (one case would be NotFound, another would be InternalServerError). See what I mean? There are standard semantics for these codes, yes, but I'd like to document API specifics.

Comment: Given your example, there should only a single case where the correct response is HTTP status code 404. It's where the requested "resource" does not exist from a business perspective. The resource could be some business object like an invoice or a product item. Any HTTP client should know how to handle "invoice not found" or "product item not found" and act accordingly. This is why we keep referring to the HTTP spec for status code documentation. Can you give an example of the "different scenatrios" you are referring to? :)

Comment: @SixtoSaez Well, for a given method, one scenario would be that the requested resource is not found => NotFound, another scenario would be that the underlying database raised an unexpected exception => InternalServerError. It'd be good to document the method's specific/possible error scenarios, as one does with .NET exceptions.

Comment: @aknuds1: HTTP 500 means exactly that, *internal* server error, i.e. you should be logging the full details on the server and not returning those internal details to the client. Just follow the HTTP status code spec to the letter and you will be fine.

Comment: @ChristianHayter Well, I still miss a way to document which errors may be thrown as with standard exceptions. Considering anyway to throw normal exceptions from my methods and translate them automatically to HttpResponseException somewhere else...

Comment: @aknuds1: You are assuming that server-side error details are going to be useful to client-side code. In practice this is usually not the case. See Sixto's detailed and useful answer.

Comment: @ChristianHayter Not really. This is more from the perspective of defining the API's behaviour. The issue arose as I was writing unit tests for a couple of controllers that implement a common interface, I wanted to document in the interface which exceptions could arise (and also test for them).

Comment: @aknuds1: Standard practice is to write your unit tests to test the controllers directly, not to call them from the far side of an HTTP link. That way you can forget about HTTP errors and test the raw exceptions that were originally thrown.

Comment: @ChristianHayter What makes you think I don't test the controller classes directly? We're talking about HttpResponseException after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that lets me document error cases in Web API controller methods as one does for normal C# exceptions - map each HTTP status code you want to use for flagging errors to a subclass of `HttpResponseException`. This solves my particular problem, which was just down to describing error cases in the documentation comments of Web API controller methods.

Consider the following code as an example:

```
public class HttpNotFoundException : HttpResponseException
{
    public HttpNotFoundException(string reason)
        : base(new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ReasonPhrase = reason })
    { }
}

public class HttpInternalServerError : HttpResponseException
{
    public HttpInternalServerError(string reason)
        : base(new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ReasonPhrase = reason })
    { }
}

public class ResourceApiController : ApiController
{
    IRepository Repository { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete a resource.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Resource ID.</param>
    /// <exception cref="HttpNotFoundException">Resource not found.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="HttpInternalServerError">An internal error was detected, for instance in database service.</exception>
    public void DeleteResourceById(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            Repository.Delete(id);
        }
        catch (WebResourceNotFoundError)
        {
            throw new HttpNotFoundException(string.Format("Build '{0}' not found", id));
        }
        catch (DatabaseServiceException)
        {
            throw new HttpInternalServerError("Database service operation failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR version**: Primarily design your exception response with codes and information the client can *act* upon. Leverage the standard HTTP status codes as much as possible. Document what you are providing above and beyond what is in the HTTP spec to guide the client app behavior. Secondarily, provide information the client developer can use for development & troubleshooting when feasible.

In designing error responses for an HTTP based API, I'd ask myself what expectations and corresponding behavior will be triggered on the client-side based on those error responses. When a client receives an HTTP status code of 500, it can assume some kind of "malfunction" has occurred in the server so that the request cannot be properly processed. The [HTTP spec for status code 500](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.5.1) says this is a kind of catchall status code when another code cannot be properly assigned; not very helpful to the client other than knowing the server just went "boom". However, there is an HTTP status code 503 Service Unavailable which provides information to the client through the `Retry-After` HTTP header on how long the outage could last.

In the specific example from the comments, telling the client that there was a database exception is not very useful because there's probably nothing the client can do about it. I'd log detailed information about exceptions on the server-side for ops/developers to use and let the HTTP status code inform the client of the issue.

The only exception I make is to provide detailed information on unexpected or missing elements (and such) when a request fails to parse. I'll send this as part of the response with an HTTP status code of 400 Bad Request. The client app probably can't do anything with that information but the client developers will really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've come to think of another scheme though, which'll let me leverage the standard exception documentation scheme. I'll give it a spin tomorrow, when I'm back at work.